# No conmmutative rings examples

Tags: ring-theory

I want to met more examples for commutative and noncommutative rings without an element unique for multiplication.
As the set of all even integers (commutative) $2\mathbb{Z}$ or the set of matrices with entries in the even integers (non-commutative) $M_{n}(2\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: I believe you mean "without an identity element (for multiplication)."

Comment: It would be a good idea to include in your question the rings you know, with and without unit. Anyway, every ideal of every ring you know is a ring without unit. What kind of examples do you want?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz “Every ideal of every ring you know is a ring without unit.” That certainly isn’t true.  Every ideal of $F\times F$ is a ring with identity, even the zero ideal.  It sounds like you are thinking of something else.

Comment: @rschwieb Yeah I was going to say "is a rng", but at the end said "a ring without identity" for fear of not being understod. It turned out to be worse, since I should have said "a ring not-necessarily-with-identity".

Comment: Now that I think about it, I have heard people saying "non-unital ring" when they actually mean "non-necesarily-unital ring". It was not my intention to conflate these, but I guess I had it internalized in my brain somehow huh.

Comment: By the way, @rsch, thanks for making me notice this! I certainly need to be more careful with language.

Answer (score 3):

Take your favorite non commutative ring $R$ with identity and consider $S$, the direct sum of infinitely many copies of $R$, with pointwise addition and multiplication. This ring is non commutative and has no identity element.

Take your favorite non commutative ring $R$ with identity and consider a proper right ideal $I$ thereof.

If $I$, considered as a ring has an identity $e$, then this is an idempotent element and so is $1-e$; moreover $I=eR$. Consider the right ideal $J=(1-e)R$. Then $R\cong I\oplus J$ as right $R$-modules, via the map $r\mapsto(er,(1-e)r)$.

So if your ring $R$ is indecomposable as right $R$-module, then $I$ is a ring without identity.